# Desalinhamento de cards no tamanho de resolução menor do bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

Boas amigos. Estou com o seguinte problema em relação ao alinhamento vertical das minhas cards, abaixo deixo a imagem e o código para melhor exemplificar. Tem como poderem me ajudar? De salientar que está dentro de um container.. Ainda estou na fase de aprendizagem...
Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 mr-3 mb-3 justify-content-sm-center">
                    <div class="card border-0" id="content-a" style="height:
                        12rem;">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Jogos da
                                Multiplicação</h4>
                            <a href="multip_game.html" class="card-link
                                text-center" style="font-size: 15pt;
                                text-decoration: underline;">&rarr;Entra e
                                joga!&larr;</a>


                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 mb-3 ">
                    <div class="card border-0 bg-warning" id="content-b"
                        style="height: 12rem;">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title text-center font-weight-bold">Jogo
                                da Divisão</h4>
                            <a href="divi_game.html" class="card-link
                                text-center" style="font-size:
                                15pt;text-decoration: underline;">&rarr;Entra e
                                joga!&larr;</a>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

<div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-5 mr-3 mb-3">
                    <div class="card border-0" id="content-c" style="height:
                        12rem;">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Jogo do Par
                                ou Impar <span class="special-word">?</span><span
                                    class="special-word3">?</span></h4>
                            <a href="par_impar_game.html" class="card-link"
                                style="font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:
                                underline;">&rarr;Entra e joga!&larr;</a>


                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5 mb-5 mb-3 ">
                    <div class="card border-0" id="content-d" style="height:
                        12rem;">
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Jogo do
                                Primo ou não primo<span class="special-word">?</span><span
                                    class="special-word3">?</span></h4>
                            <a href="prim_game.html" class="card-link"
                                style="font-size: 15pt;text-decoration:
                                underline;">&rarr;Entra e joga!&larr;</a>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Gostaria de alinhar as cards para que fiquem alinhadas umas as outras. Na imagem é possível ver que a primeira card está alinhada com a terceira card e a segunda está alinhada com a ultima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado... Já consegui resolver o meu problema, acabei introduzindo todos os cards numa unica row e para cada card criei uma col-sm-6, fazendo que quando a linha ja tivesse dois elementos a preencher 12 colunas automaticamente as restantes cards passassem para baixo.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que essa imagem foi tirada em mobile, o erro é exatamente a margin adicionada com a classe `mr-3`, como já citado.
Porém uma alternativa é utilizar a api de responsividade do bootstrap 4.
Adicionando alterando `mr-3` para `mr-sm-3`, e então você terá a margem na direita apenas do tamanho `sm` para cima, excluindo as margens no mobile ou `xs`.

Answer (score 0):

O problema são essas classes `.mr-3` que aplica um `margin-right` em algumas divs fazendo com que elas fiquem menores quando a tela está em `.col-sm-` (até 575px de largura).

Você pode usar um media query no CSS para resetar essas margens:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 575px){
   .mr-3{
      margin-right: 0 !important;
   }
}
```